# Firing an Event in Automation Studio doesn't work after Firing Event via REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I created a journey, added an Entry Source of type "Contact Data Entry Event". Data Extension I am trying to pull data from is linked to this Entry Event. Then I created an automation flow with a Fire Event activity and ran the automation. It worked well and data from the DE was pushed to the journey. I did it several times and everything worked fine.

Then I triggered (fired) the same event via REST API - https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events and it worked just well.

BUT when I tried firing the event via automation studio again, nothing happened. I did everything as usual: cleaned the DE, uploaded data with overwrite option and launched the automation. I did it several times and still no luck.

Does anybody know why it is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, don't mix firing Journeys by API and Automations. As Trump would say, "those bad people out there, they want our interactions. But they can't have them. Because they're really bad. And Journey Builder's doing the most amazing things... just great things... they're just great".

It's a faithy thing.

Comment: I think HWM it's not a problem in this case.  HWM is an "indication point" unique per data source (usually data extension), which indicates Marketing Cloud's mechanism which records were already processed. Dependently on Automation/Journey settings, HWM can be ignored (MC just display information that processing of such data source can be slow) and all records can be evaluated each time.  With one statement I fully agree - **do not mix firings**. I can't explain why exactly, but triggering methods do not mix well.

Comment: I deliberated for a bit on that answer, thinking about how HWM would fit my "don't mix" response. Trouble is, the Stack Exchange Gestapo don't go for my "in short" or "anecdotally" responses. I'm inclined to leave them to their mutual upvoting.

Comment: If the Gestapo part is related somehow to my comment, then I am sorry, it wasn't intended anyhow.

Comment: No. Not at all. I agreed with your feedback completely.